# How can I write a json webpage into a json file using selenium driver.page_source?

Tags: python, json, selenium

I have found a json response of a webpage and scraped it with selenium using the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "website.json"
driver.get(url)
text = driver.page_source

with open("data.json", "tw",encoding="utf-8") as html_file:
    html_file.write(text)
```

But when I open the file it is like this:

```
<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{
  "Status": "OK",
  "TotalRows": 386,
  "Items": [
   ...
   ]
}</pre></body></html>
```

So the json file shows in the middle of two html tags. To solve this problem I have tried this code:

```
t1 = text.replace('<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">', "")
t2 = t1.replace('</pre></body></html>', "")

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(t2, outfile, indent=2)
```

But when I run this, data.json contains strings like this:

```
"{\n  \"Status\": \"OK\",\n  \"TotalRows\": 401,\n  \"Items\": [\n  ...\n  ]\n}"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to find only the element you want and extract it's text:

```py
driver.get(url)
element = driver.findElement(By.TAG_NAME, 'pre')
with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(element.text, file)
```

Comment: I found the json file from the `Network tab` of inspect element. So I need the whole json file of my url.

Comment: What is the problem with the string you have received? It is a valid JSON which you can save to a file.

Comment: I have tried `requests` and `bs4` too, but the cloudflare protects it. So I must just use selenium. May be this occurs due to cloudflare as well!

Answer (score 0):

It seems after cleaning the `HTML tags` through:

```
t1 = text.replace('<html><head></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">', "")
t2 = t1.replace('</pre></body></html>', "")
```

I need to load `t2` as a json file as below:

```
res = json.loads(t2)
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(res, outfile, indent=4)
```

This worked for me.